# How to change the base class variables with the derived class object-c++

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
  int a,b,c;
  A()
  {
      a=0;
      b=0;
      c=0;
  }
};

class B:public A
{
public:
    void get()
    {
        A *a2 =new A;
        a2->a=10;
        a2->b=20;
        a2->c=30;
        cout<<a2->a<<""<<a2->b<<""<<a2->c<<""<<endl;
        cout<<"Checking!"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *a1 = new A;
    B *b1 = new B;
    cout<<a1->a<<""<<a1->b<<""<<a1->c<<""<<endl;
    b1->a=10;
    b1->b=20;
    b1->c=30;
    cout<<b1->a<<""<<b1->b<<""<<b1->c<<""<<endl;

    b1->get();//cant able to change the variables of the base class object with the derived class object
    cout<<a1->a<<""<<a1->b<<""<<a1->c<<""<<endl;//will print the same values..

    //b1->get();

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
000
102030
102030
Checking!
000
Press any key to continue . . .
```

//The address of the variables that is holded by the derived class object is different from the address of the variables that is holded by the base class object.Isnt..
//But is there any possiblity to change the variables of the base class through the derived class object..

Comment: Please learn to format your code for display here. Select it in the editor and then press  the curly brackets button above it.

Comment: @unaperson:Thanks.Will do it from my next question onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `get()` method, you are actually creating a temporary instance of Base `class A`, which has nothing to do with the class getting derived. Simply remove `a2` from everywhere in your `get()` and try it. You will be able to see the changes happening.

[Note: Base class object is automatically allocated when derived object is allocated. That means when you do `new B`, it will allocate memory for `B` and `A`]

### Edit:

For your question, your `get()` should be like this:

```
void get()
{
    a=10;
    b=20;
    c=30;
    cout<<a<<b<<c<<endl;
    cout<<"Checking!"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: If i modify the variable with the derived class object and if i'm accesing it with the base class object the variable should give the changed value(done by the derived class).I deleted the a2 object .but still the value is not changed to 102030.its printing me 000 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating a new A inside the get function, just:

```
cout << a << b << c << "\n";
```

or if you want to be more explicit:

```
cout << this->a << this->b << this->c << "\n";
```

Comment: if you are stuck on using a pointer you could replace the `a2=new A` with `a2 = this`. `this` is a pointer to the "current object"